# Prove $g=\sum_{n\in J}\hat f(n)e_n$

Tags: fourier-analysis, riemann-integration

> For every finite set of integers $J\subset\mathbb{Z},$ let us define the linear space $E_J=\text{span}\{e_n:n\in J\},$ where $e_n(t)=e^{int}.$
>
> Let $f:\mathbb{T}\to \mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable function, and $g\in E_J$ a function such that
>
> $$||f-g||_{L_2}=\inf\{||f-h||_{L_2}:h\in E_J\}$$
>
> $(a)$ Prove $g=\sum_{n\in J}\hat f(n)e_n,$ where $\hat f(n)$ is the $n-$th Fourier coefficient.
>
> $(b)$ Find $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following minimum occurs:
>
> $$\min_{a,b,c}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \big | \ |t|-ae^{2it}-be^{3it}-ce^{10it} \ \big |^2dt$$

---

My thoughts:

$g$ is a trigonometric polynomial, and we know that the trigonometric polynomial, which best approximates a function is it's Fourier series in $L_2.$

I tried to use that combined with what's given of $g$, but got stuck.

As for $(b)$, using what was proved in $(a),$ I think $a=\hat f(2), b = \hat f(3), c = \hat f (10),$ for $f=|t|,$ but not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As for b), you are right. For a) you can show, in general, that for a metric space $V$ with subspace $W$ spanned by orthonormal vectors $\{e_i\}$, the best approximation of $v\in V$ by elements of $W$ is given by $v=(v\cdot e_1)e_1+\cdots$. This implies a), using the usual metric structure on trigonometric polynomials.

Comment: @user90189 Metric spaces were only mentioned in my course, so I'm not really familiar with them. Mind elaborating?

Comment: Dear @Itay4, since a saw the $L^2$ norm, I thought you were taught about inner products. You can read, e.g., in Calculus from Apostol, V. II, chap. I. If you don't want to use any general theory, but your bare hands, you may expand the real function $\int |f-\sum_Ja_ne^{int}|^2\,dt=\int |f|^2+\cdots$, (you can do this). Next you may write $a_n=x_n+iy_n$, you can use calculus to look for the critical point, to find out that the coefficients $a_n$ coincide with the Fourier coefficients, and by the way, you can see that the minimum is unique.

Comment: @user90189 I don't get the desired result. I should differentiate $\int|f|^2-|2f\sum_J(x_n+iy_n)e^{int}|+|\sum_J(x_n+iy_n)e^{int}|^2 ?$

Comment: Dear @Itay4, expand completely and evaluate as much integrals as you can, for example, the last term should be $\sum_{n\in J}|a_n|^2$, for $a_n=x_n+iy_n$. At the end, you can differentiate to find the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be as stated, and suppose $g = \sum_{n\in J}\langle f,e_n\rangle e_n$. Then
$$
               (f-g)\perp e_n,\;\;\; n\in J.
$$
In particular, $\langle f-g,h\rangle =0$ for all $h \in E_J$, which gives $(f-g)\perp E_J$ and
$$
        \|f-h\|^2 = \|(f-g)+(g-h)\|^2 = \|f-g\|^2+\|g-h\|^2.
$$
Hence,
$$
           \|f-h\|^2 \ge \|f-g\|^2,\;\;\; h\in E_J,
$$
with equality iff $\|g-h\|=0$ or $g=h$. This proves (a).

Part (b) requires finding a,b,c such that
$$
            \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\{ |t|-ae^{2it}-be^{3it}-ce^{10it} \} e^{-2it}dt =0 \\
      \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\{ |t|-ae^{2it}-be^{3it}-ce^{10it} \} e^{-3it}dt =0 \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\{ |t|-ae^{2it}-be^{3it}-ce^{10it} \} e^{-10it}dt =0
$$
This is a system of 3 equations in the 3 unknowns $a,b,c$.

Comment: So you're assuming $g$ is as wanted, and proving it is minimum, right? Could you please explain two things: 1. Why $(f-g) \perp e_n$ is that true? 2. In the 4th line shouldn't be an inequality by triangle inequality?

Comment: $(f-g)\perp e_n$ for $n\in J$ follows by direct computation. The 4th line follows directly from the 3rd line.

Comment: I still can't understand the 4th line, must be missing something simple here.. Mind elaborating?

Comment: @Itay4 Do you mean my second equation, where $f-g$ is orthogonal to every $e_n$ for $n\in J$ and, hence, also to everything in the closure of the linear span of such $e_n$, which includes $g-h$.

Comment: I still can't see how that yields the second equality..

Comment: @Itay4 $g-h$ is in $E_J$. That $(f-g) \perp E_J$ can be checked directly. So $f-g$ is orthogonal to $g-h$. So $f-h = (f-g)+(g-h)$ is an orthogonal decomposition. By Pythagoras, $\|f-h\|^2=\|f-g\|^2+\|g-h\|^2$, from which $\|f-h\| \ge \|f-g\|$ follows, and the two are equal iff $\|g-h\|=0$, which is equivalent to $g=h$.

Comment: @Itay4  You're welcome.